# Functional form of density with approxfun

Tags: r, approximation, density-plot

I got a problem while trying to approximate the functional form of a density in R with `approxfun()`. The minimal example is as follows.

```
Example = seq(0.5, 1.5, 0.005)
dens = density(Example)
estim = approxfun(dens) 
plot(estim)
plot(dens)
```

The problem is that `plot(estim)`gives the following plot [image]

but `plot(dens)`gives the full plot,

[image]

with the x-axis covering all values and not stopping at 1 as with the approxfun plot. Hence, `approxfun()` does not appropriately capture the density.

What am I doing wrong here? I did try several configurations of `approxfun` in order to somehow include the whole x-axis but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `estim` variable is just a function at that point. It doesn't remember the range of data that was used to create it. When plotting a function, you will need to tell R where to start and stop (By default R will plot a function from x=0 to x=1). For example

```
plot(estim, xlim=range(Example))
```

[image]

Note that `range(Example)` only covers the observed range. If you want to use the same range as the density plot, use

```
plot(estim, xlim=range(dens$x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the `range()` command in the plot function. I always changed it in the `approxfun()` command.